# TypeScript React: Infer prop type from generic

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that fetches data from an API and then displays it in a table. I have a prop that allows a value that is fetched to be displayed differently in the table. This is how I have the prop types right now:

```js
// T is the type of the row, so the data fetched from the API has type T[]
type Props<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  columns: Record<keyof T, ColumnSetting<T>>;
}

type ColumnSetting<T> = {
  header: string;
  customValue?: (value: any, row: T) => React.ReactNode;
}
```

But I don't want to use `any` for the value, I want it to have the correct type. So for example in the example below I want it to infer that the type of `value` is `number` (and not `string`), is this possible?

```js
<CustomTable<{ title: string, percentage: number }>
  columns={{ 
    title: {
      header: 'Title'
    },
    percentage: { 
      header: 'Percentage', 
      customValue: value => value + '%' 
    }
  }}
/>
```

If tried adding another generic for the key or adding a generic to `customValue` but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use a custom mapped type instead of `Record`:

```
type Props<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  columns: { [P in keyof T]: ColumnSetting<T, T[P]> };
}

type ColumnSetting<T, V> = {
  header: string;
  customValue?: (value: V, row: T) => React.ReactNode;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoAekrgBU5gBnOGACyRYE8wOJMX2cHAHcANHEYQBHACYoYKOJiQw07GUpx42HAIIAFAJJxWKZjG4daAbQC6FCzzj6cYRgB56SAB4wkAOxlmZDRoGXdGGChgfwBzcQBXfwBrfwhhfwA+TLgAXjgAbwo4OFCAGwSQf0YALkK4a30GfzhkpE4+Ols6gGEICqqAZRUYGNjPcRt9WxyAXwBuClmKB0s4PoH-YZhRuIm4ADUc-KLyEvYUGSQoOsjouMWz0oTI3AOUCqQAfjqACgA3D4JJB1A7iER1WgASjyOWQ6BgADp4RgAHIQK6PZbkTBJDDACAtHovGC4WgoABGZSQnjgPj8gWCSFCUHCdzGiRSaQy2V+YDqLggbk8mRhpxKJSIMASUBa7ky7komSWK3IFFC1XgUDycHcxNeIHJVJpBRYwBg1NuUQ5cB4UDQAQUsRBcH8lQp1zgs2VT3KlWquQKpuKEtGFpd4ol51QVxuBFo5up+FEIajaBJbyBLoBMNyOX+KaoNCjJdLJQAel9U17C1G7Q7-E6I3Bq9HLtc6vh9NcG03ky2nmmMyB3p86oDPrC4BPgXAANQEACk+AH1DL64ller2JKs2xSqAA)

Answer (score 0):

```js
type Props<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  columns: Record<keyof T, ColumnSetting<T>>;
};

// Define your ColumnSetting type with the correct type for the value parameter
type ColumnSetting<T> = {
  header: keyof T;
  customValue?: (value: T[keyof T], row: T) => React.ReactNode; // Use T[keyof T] instead of any
};

// Define your CustomTable component with the generic parameter T
function CustomTable<T extends Record<string, unknown>>({ columns }: Props<T>) {
  // Your CustomTable implementation here
  return null;
}

<CustomTable<{ percentage: number }>
  columns={{
    percentage: {
      header: 'percentage',
      customValue: (value) => value + '%',
    },
  }}
/>
```

this should do the trick for what you want to do

Comment: That's unfortunately not what I'm looking for, because if T has other properties with other types, it can be any of those types.

Comment: I've updated my example to show what I mean, hopefully it is more clear now